# SPARQL query relates records like one-many

Tags: sparql, jena

I have this type of model(schema)

```
1 product hasOffer (many) Offers 
1 offer hseRule (many) shipment rules
```

like

```
Product(1)--->Offer(N)----->Rules(M)
```

How can I query 
one product with all offers and all shipping rules.
In simple words.
 **How can I query one-many related records ?**

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a simple SPARQL query with multiple triples in the WHERE clause. This works because the graph model over which SPARQL queries naturally joins data together.

eg.

```
SELECT ?product ?offer ?rules 
 WHERE { {?product ns:hasOffer ?offer} {?offer ns:hasRules ?rules} }
```

Source: Running the same example in Protege with this query.

EDIT:

Question: is there any way to construct as product{ offers:{ rules:{} }, productAttributes } ?

Answer: Yes there is, you can add `?attribute` to the `SELECT` clause the triple `?product ns:productAttribute ?attribute` to the `WHERE` clause (or multiple such clauses if you have attributes across multiple data properties).
 However I would strongly recommend you refrain from doing so. The query is going to return a potentially large set of data similar to an SQL result set. Thus you are going to see multiple rows with the same product and having a product attribute there will make your life unnecessarily difficult, since that attribute will appear in all rows with that product. Instead run a separate query where you only get the products and their attributes.

Comment: You don't need the extra {}{} `SELECT ?product ?offer ?rules 
 WHERE { ?product ns:hasOffer ?offer . ?offer ns:hasRules ?rules }` or if you don't want the ?offer returned, just ?product and ?rules: 
`{ ?product ns:hasOffer/ns:hasRules ?rules }`

Comment: Is there any way to construct as  product{ offers:{ rules:{} }, productAttributes }  ?

Comment: See. product attributes like brand, title e.t.c and inside product block( object ) i want to get offers related to that product and same as rules inside of offers. Thank you.

Comment: So then in your model productAttributes are strings associated with Products correct?

Comment: Hi Mr. @AndyS can you please help me to get my result ? thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing my answer is not what you are looking for, can you provide an example of what you expect your result set to look like?